# Sell scripts built on framework

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

I was wondering if it is allowed to create commercial scripts (scripts for sale) that are built on a framework like Laravel or Codeigniter?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Do you mean a fully-packaged solution *on top of* Laravel or CI? Or do you mean a standalone piece of software *to use in tandem with* Laravel or CI?

Comment: "a fully-packaged solution on top of Laravel or CI"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Laravel and CodeIgniter use the [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License):

> ...
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> ...

You are free to sell your own derivative works without worry.

Comment: But anyone who bought your work, can resell it as often as he wants, right?

Comment: @Adam Only if you decide to retain the MIT license. If you should update the project to utilize your own proprietary license, then I believe any clients using your platform will be held to your license agreement and not the original MIT license. I don't know the finer points since I'm not a lawyer, but if you're rolling out any SAAS products, then it's likely that you'll want to consult a lawyer in regards to these questions as well as drafting out a more rigid license to prevent any clients from re-selling or abusing your product.